# How can i make marshaller for tree-like case class?

Tags: scala, marshalling, circe

I want to make marshaller for case class which has fields referred to the same class.

```scala
case class TreeNode (name: String, parentNode: Option[TreeNode])
```

if i make serializer

```scala
implicit val nodeJson = jsonFormat2(TreeNode)
```

i get an error that no imlicits found for parameter Option[TreeNode]
is there are any way to solve such problem except writing serialization from scratch?

PS Some more attempts i made with encoder

```scala
private def toNode (node: TreeNode): Map[String, Any] = {
    val parent = node.parentNode.map(toNode).orNull
    Map[String, Any] ("name" -> node.name, "parentNode" -> parent)
  }

implicit val treeNodeEncoder: Encoder[TreeNode] =
  Encoder.forProduct2("name", "parentNode")(n =>
    (n.name, n.parentNode.map(toNode).orNull)
  )
```

it does not work as well, because Map[String, Any] has no implicit either

Comment: What does **cats-effect** has to do with this? From where does that `Encoder` comes from? **circe**?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes io.circe

Comment: Is the class hierarchy `sealed`? Circe needs sealed hierarchy to be able to implicitly create Encoders/Decoders.

Comment: You can't get an `Encoder[String,Any]`, but you don't need it either. Just reuse the `treeNodeEncoder` to recursively encode `parentNode` when it's not `null`. But circe should be able to do this out of the box too.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I do not need anythiong, i just learn, so any options are welcomed. Thank you very much for this one, custom encoding i already learned. This way you provided i just do not like that empty parentNode still presents in json as null. Is there are any options to make it absent, just  `{"name":"root"}` instead of  `{"name":"root","parentNode":null}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**circe** supports this out of the box, you just need to use the [semiautomatic / automatic derivation](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/semiauto-derivation.html) mechanism provided by the library.
You can also modify the printer you want to use to control the identation and if you want to include or not `nulls`

Take a look to this code:

```
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder, Printer, parser}
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

final case class TreeNode(name: String, parentNode: Option[TreeNode] = None)
object TreeNode {
  implicit final val decoder: Decoder[TreeNode] = deriveDecoder
  implicit final val encoder: Encoder[TreeNode] = deriveEncoder
}

val data = TreeNode(name = "child", parentNode = Some(TreeNode(name = "parent")))

val printer = Printer.spaces2SortKeys.copy(dropNullValues = true)
val json = printer.print(data.asJson)
println(json)

println("------------------")

val result = parser.decode[TreeNode](json)
println(result)
```

You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/z601d8yNRMSMJHdvk9NvCg/6)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to make this work with circe, here is a working example:

```scala
import io.circe.{Encoder,Decoder}
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.{deriveEncoder,deriveDecoder}
import io.circe.syntax._

final case class TreeNode (name: String, parentNode: Option[TreeNode])

object TreeNode {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[TreeNode] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[TreeNode] = deriveDecoder
}

val a = TreeNode("a", None)
val b = TreeNode("b", Some(a))
val c = TreeNode("c", Some(b))

println(c.asJson)
```

Output

```
{
  "name" : "c",
  "parentNode" : {
    "name" : "b",
    "parentNode" : {
      "name" : "a",
      "parentNode" : null
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that representing trees starting from the leaves rather than the roots is unusual.

Comment: "representing trees starting from the leaves rather than the roots is unusual" - yes, it is just to simplify example

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for help, just to make it complete one more way i discovered, how to make it manually if necesserily

```
implicit val treeNodeEncoder: Encoder[TreeNode] = new Encoder[TreeNode] {
    def apply(a: TreeNode): Json = {
      val list = List(
        ("name" -> Json.fromString(a.name)),
        ("parentNode" -> a.parentNode.map(this.apply).orNull),
      ).filterNot(_._2 == null)

      Json.obj(list: _*)
    }
  }
```

This way we can avoid to write parentNode as null and just skip it if it is None